# switch generator output

Tags: python, generator

I have a task where I need to 'switch' the output of a generator mid-flow based on some condition.

Lets say that we have a generator which is yielding data from some infinite source. Every time we read 1GB of data from the generator we switch the output to some other reader.

```
input = MyInfiniteGenerator()
Reader1(input) # does something with the first gigabyte of data
Reader2(input) # does something with the second gigabyte of data
...
```

When we come to switch the output from Reader1 to Reader2, Reader1 should be closed. I cannot change how the readers behave, they simply iterate over the input.

This problem is analogous to a rotating file log.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest wrapping your generator in another generator that will only read the amount you want. `itertools.islice` should do the job nicely:

```
import itertools

gen = someInfiniteGenerator()

while True:
    slice = itertools.islice(gen, 1000000) # reads one million items from gen
    reader = Reader(slice) # consumes all of the slice
```

The only potential issue with this is that if `gen` ever does end (that is, it raises `StopIteration`) you won't ever detect it unless Reader flips out if it gets an empty generator. If this is apossability, you can work around it with an extra level of generator that checks that there's at least one item in the generator before yielding anything:

```
class EmptyGenerator(Exception):
    pass

def notEmptyGen(gen):
    try:
        first = next(gen)
        yield first
    except StopIteration: # empty source generator
        raise EmptyGenerator()

    yield from gen
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
input_chunk = (i for _, i in zip(xrange(chunk_size), input)) # `range` in Python3
```

or, perhaps more generally,

```
from itertools import takewhile    
input_chunk = takewhile(condition, input)
```

and feed `input_chunk` to `Reader1`, etc.

`condition` must be a function taking one argument -- the items of `input`.

Also note that `input` is the name of a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), and using it as a variable name you will shadow it.

The docs on [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

Comment: This would require the readers to be created before we start iterating over the source. Reader2..3..4.. should only be created when the handover is going to happen - at the 1GB boundary.

Comment: @LeeTreveil Maybe it's just me, but I don't get the idea. Maybe if you could provide a more detailed example of the code, it would help.